# A word that describes giving its name to something else: iron is ... for ferromagnetism

Tags: word-choice

I am writing about unusual ferromagnetic materials. For the introduction I want to use the "namegiver" for ferromagnetism, iron, as an example but I am stuck finding the right word or expression.

> - In iron the *namegiving* element for ferromagnetism the Curie temperature...
> - In iron, which coined the term ferromagnetism the Curie temperature ...
> - In iron, from which the term ferromagnetism is derived, the Curie temperature ...

Is there an English word that expresses that iron, or to be more precise, its Latin counterpart "ferrum", gave its name to the phenomenon *ferromagnetism*?

Comment: If you were talking about "ferrum," you'd say it's the root word. In this case, I'd say something like "iron, which is the basis for the term 'ferromagnetism.'"

Comment: Iron is the **archetypal** ferromagnetic material.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Iron (*ferrum*) is the **eponym**[¹](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eponym) of *ferromagnetism*.

Many people would also say that *ferrum* and *ferromagnetism* are **namesakes**.[²](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namesake) It might be insisted by some pedants that *ferromagnetism* is the **namesake** of *ferrum*, not the other way around, though the word’s etymology does not bear this up.

Answer (score 2):

> The term *ferromagnetism* derives its first element from the Latin word for iron, *ferrum*.

Comment: Yes. Exactly. The name does **not** come from the English word _iron_; rather, it uses a borrowed word. This is the norm in English. In exactly the opposite way, German **translates** elemental names like _Hydrogen_ and _Oxygen_ (Gk 'water source' and 'acid source') into _Wasserstoff_ and _Sauerstoff_.

Comment: @JohnLawler I presume you’ve read [Poul Anderson’s *Uncleftish Beholding*](http://www.grijalvo.com/Citas/Peculiar_English.htm) then?

Comment: Oh, yes, many years ago. I've read most of Anderson. Have you read Barnes's [_English Speech-Craft_](http://books.google.com/books?id=K60VAAAAYAAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=twopage)?